# Android set Drawable background in TextView from Adapter for API 21

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drawable

I am facing issue change color or drawable resource programmatically from the recycler adapter `holder` for API 21.

In the below code, I am changing the drawable resource for blow API 23 but nothing is happening. I have tried to change the drawable background color neither that work.

> I would prefer to change only background tint if possible for API 21
>   so I can avoid using extra drawable but if not possible than I can use
>   one.

**Note:** *For default style, I have set TextView background (drawable) in `<style>`.*

### RecyclerView Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull StepHolder holder, int position) {

    Step step = mStep.get(position);

    holder.setCount(step.getCount());
    holder.setDescription(step.getDescription());

    if (position <= 2) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
            // change drawable color property
            holder.count.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_circle_accent);

        } else {
            holder.count.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
        }

    }

}
```

### ViewHolder

```
public class StepHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView count, description;
    public View timeline;

    public StepHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.count       = itemView.findViewById(R.id.v_step_count);
        this.description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.v_step_description);
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count.setText(count);
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description.setText(description);
    }

    public void setTimeline(View timeline) {
        this.timeline = timeline;
    }
}
```

### Modal

```
public class Step {

    private String count, description;

    public Step(String count, String description) {
        this.count       = count;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Step{" +
                "count='" + count + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

### View

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/v_step_count"
    style="@style/StepsCounterTheme"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/app_space"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/app_space"
    android:text="@string/_1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/v_step_timeline_path"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v_step_description"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />
```

### Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
</shape>
```

### Style

> Here I have realized the issue is with the style. Means if I set the
>   `backgroundTint` in style, the code for API < 23 won't affect. Once I
>   have tried removing `backgroundTint` from style. The code is working.

```
<!-- steps to prepare timeline counter theme -->
<style name="StepsCounterTheme" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/app_space_ot</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/app_space_ot</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_circle</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colorPrimary</item> <!-- this one -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

> **Question**
>
> So now I wonder how to set the default `backgroundTint` in style? Do I
>   have to create version specific style? Will that allow overriding in
>   Java for API < 23?

Comment: what is holder.count? is this the correct textview variable?

Comment: Yes, it is a correct TextView. I am setting text for the same object.

Comment: @karan I have updated questions with all sources. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
holder.count.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_circle_accent));
            holder.count.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorD));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void setBackgroundColor (TextView tv){
    GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) tv.getBackground();
    bgShape.mutate();
    bgShape.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext.getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent));
}
```

> Usage

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
    setBackgroundColor(holder.count);
} else {
    holder.count.setBackgroundTintList(mContext.getColorStateList(R.color.colorAccent));
}
```

I don't know if I understood the question well. haha..

Comment: So what is different in my reference code for API < 23? I am having issue only for API < 23 however the `else` condition API > 23 using `setBackgroundTintList` is workig fine.

Comment: @CodeLover Sorry I misunderstood the question: /

Comment: No problem. Do you have any resolution or idea to fix it?

Comment: I changed it. Please check.

Comment: I think you understood the question now. I have a problem changing Oval shape drawable color in API < 23. 

I have tried your updated code, but that too didn't work. Just one more thing, my drawable is a `Shape`, and here you have set the GradientDrawable. Does that make any difference?

Comment: I have workaround to find the reason why this code is not working. The main issue is in Style. As your code is working fine if I remove `backgroundInt` from style. But in that case, I have to set the else condition as well that will not set any default color in style or xml.

Comment: Is there any reason to use backgroundTint?
Since backgroundTint works only on API21, I think it is better to find a more flexible way to use it.

Comment: Yes, because I am using same drawable in different places that have different colors.

Comment: So how about deleting the backgroundTint option and using setBackgroundColor () I posted?
No special else option is needed, just set the color.

Comment: It is suggested to delete     'if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <23) ' condition and use only 
    'setBackgroundColor (holder.count)'